# Android AsyncTask: Will methods that are called inside doInBackground() executed in main or background thread?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Lets say i have a class which contains inner class that is named `fooTask` that extends `AsyncTask` and a method named `getFoo()` that returns some int value. If i call this `getFoo()` method inside `AsyncTask's doInBackground()` method, will this `getFoo()` method be executed in main or background thread?

```
public class SomeClass extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fooTask task = new fooTask();
        task.execute();
    }

    private class fooTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>{

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            int foo = getFoo();
            return foo;
        }

    }

    private int getFoo(){
        // Will this method be executed in main or background thread?
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be called from your background thread. It doesn't matter where the method is located in code, it matters where it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you write inside doInBackground runs in the background. It has no connection with your GUI or different thread.

Answer (score 1):

everything inside [doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) runs in the background, unless you wrap some block of code inside [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: You can also be extreme and call `doInBackground` directly from the main thread :)

Answer (score 1):

It will be executed in background thread as mentioned in the `AsyncTask` documentation ,

> This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

link to android documentation  [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a method which runs in background (or main) thread - it's bytecode. However, bytecode can be scheduled for execution in any thread.

In particular, if you'll call `doInBackground` directly from the main thread - it will run on the main thread. If you'll leave implementation as it is (won't access this method directly) - it will run in background thread.